# Docker y sql Server

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

Soy nuevo en el mundo Docker. Tengo hecho un desarrollo de una página web que funciona tanto en desarrollo como en producción sin problema. Dicha aplicación tiene como gestor de base de datos Sql Server. Con la aplicación Docker Desktop he empaquetado la aplicación y, aparentemente, no ha dado ningún problema. El tema es que al acceder a la base de datos da el siguiente error:

"SqlException: Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON"

Cuando cambio la cadena de conexión e intento conectarme con usuario y contraseña de Sql Server da el siguiente error:

"Win32Exception: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted."
"SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)"

¿Hay que cambiar la configuración en Sql Server o cambiar la cadena de conexión?

Gracias de antemano, un saludo.